# Firefox nightly text input fields on the webpages are missing

Tags: firefox, textbox, nightly-build

I installed and used nightly-build of firefox on my machine for years. Today, I've encountered the situation stated as the title of this post, which is rather wired to me: The text input fields such as, the ones for typing user-id, password, or some words to search, are missing! And the same website rendered in Chrome or IE8 seems perfect as usual. For example, some site needs its user to type his/her id and the corresponding password looks like [this](http://img.ly/zFdi); while, the current display becomes [this](http://img.ly/zFdk).

Could anyone tell me how to fix this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Mozilla team noticed this mistake very quickly and restarting Nightly and having it update should solve the problem.